# Html : how to get value of input from form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got the following code:

```
<form method='POST' onsubmit='javascript:searchAndUpdateGrid(GET_THE_VALUE_OF_INPUT);return false;'
<input type="text" id="inputField" class="form-control" placeholder="Type something...">
</form>
```

I want to launch the function searchAndUpdateGrid with the value entered by the user in the input field. How can I do that ? (I would like to avoid to get it from Javascript)

Thanks !

Comment: `I would like to avoid to get it from Javascript` and how you expect to get the value?

Comment: This makes no sense. You want to "avoid to get it from JavaScript", but... your entire question is about how to use JavaScript to get this value.

Comment: Try to put your submit in a function and get the value of the input

Comment: the searchAndUpdateGrid would be called from the same item, I would use searchAndUpdateGrid(this.value) . No way to use something similar to 'this.value' to get the value of another item ? (I am a newbie in html :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it easy. You must write some javascript code for **onkeyup event** to doing that.

```
$(document).on('keyup','#inputField',function(){
   searchAndUpdateGrid();
});

function searchAndUpdateGrid(){
   var inputtxt = $('#inputField').val();
   $.post('file.php',{text:inputtxt},function(data){
      //type statement for after success the server request.
      //Example you must put the result of destination file in to the 
     //HTML div that we assume it's id 'preview' then
     //you should be type that code
     $('#preview').append(data);
   });
}
```

It will working fine.....
This is Jquery AJAX post method. But you can use GET method. If you using get method then you should change **$.post** to **$.get**. Another problum is what is inside the curly brackets?This is the parameter of you hoping to send textbox values to destination php or asp file.It might send your textbox values as **text** parameter.

Comment: Ok, what I want to do is not possible... I have to use Javascript, jQuery or Ajax ! Thanks.

Comment: I'm changed my answer. Please re-read that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$("#inputField").val()` would give you the value of the input (with the help of jQuery). You are using javascript and looking for a javascript function - so there is no way to not get it from javascript. alternatively you can use PHP and get the value from the file that gets the form (the one specified in the 'action' attribute) with `$_POST['inputName']`